# Convert terraform array to string

Tags: arrays, list, terraform, hcl

I have a terraform array/list

```
r53_zone_names = [
  "google.com.",
  "example.com.",
]
```

But I wish to convert it to sting for sending it to external-dns helm chart, it asks for such one:

```
"{google.com.,example.com.}"
```

How to do that with HCL? Terraform v1.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `format` and `join`:

```
> format("{%s}",join(",",local.r53_zone_names))
"{google.com.,example.com.}"
```